# Where is the content cache when using apply_filters('the_content...?

Tags: filters, post-content

The following code block is giving me an accumulated result:

```
foreach($sections as $section) {
    $content_post = get_post($section->ID);
    $content = $content_post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    echo $content;
}
```

If I catch the value of `$content` *before* the `apply_filters()`, it seems to work fine, but after and each result is appended to the previous value of `$content`.

If I change the final line to:

```
$content = wpautop($content);
```

It works as I want (I only need the paragraph formatting), but I am frustrated as I do not understand why the previous method hasn't worked.

Comment: Your initial code makes no sense to me. You are just overwriting `$content` repeatedly, without doing anything with it. Could you provide larger example of code in context?

Comment: I have pulled out the section that echo's the value of $content, as it is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to replicate the problem you're describing. I'm guessing it has to do with one of two things:

An issue with `$sections` - how exactly is this populated?

**or**

A hook to `'the_content'` somewhere else in your code - perhaps a filter function you wrote has a bug in it causing the duplicate content?